# Query string value is lost after page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

This shows the patient details page when `<a href="" />` is clicked (anchor tag is inside repeater):

```js
function showPatient(Pid) {                          
    RedirectToPage("Patient_Registration.aspx","pid="+Pid);
    return false;
}
```

```asp
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPatientList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterPatientList_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" onclick="return showPatient('<%#Eval("PID") %>')"><%#Eval("Patient_Name")%></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am getting `pID` as query string on patient details page. After getting `pID` on first page load the patient information is filled into the respective text fields. But when I click the save button `pID` is lost - getting 0 as value so that the insert query always fires.

```c#
int pID;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["pid"]);

    if (pID != 0)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            FillPatientInfo(pID);
        }
    } 
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pID ==0)
    {
        //insert query code
    }
    else
    {
        //update query code
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using Response.Redirect any where in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the QueryString - the code in the JavaScript RedirectToPage() method reads the QueryString and outputs it as form elements and then submits to the target page.

This works fine the first time but as soon as the page posts back the value is lost so this behaviour is correct.

You should either store the value somewhere (ViewState, Session etc) or add a HiddenField to the page and populate it on first load, then on postback you can pull the value from the HiddenField.

**Edit**

To go the hiddenfield route add a control into your ASPX page like this

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidField" />
```

And then alter your PageLoad like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            pID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["pid"]);
            if(pID != 0)
            {
                FillPatientInfo(pID);
                hidField.Value = pID;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pID = Convert.ToInt32(hidField.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can i do it...using hiddenfield

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin.. i have 1 problem how can pass one pID as querystring from Patient_Registration.aspx to Create_Order.aspx ..but querystring can not display in url.i have no idea how to pass from server side code.

Comment: @harsh for something as simple as an ID I would just save it in a Session var and then retrieve it on the Create Order page (see this for further details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Comment: Here my PM say dont use session thts why kevin

Comment: Then your options are very limited - I would suggest using the same sort of idea as you already have in RedirectToPage() i.e having a method in JavaScript which takes the pID as an argument, creates form elements and then submits it to the Create Order page.

Comment: did u know Kevin how to call javascript function through <a></a> tag ..means after i fire insert query pass the pid to create_orders.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

You must get pid again in save button. You are setting the value of pid from query string on postback == false. So when save button is click it does post back therefore the value of pid in querystring in not assigned to class variable pid.

Also use Request.QueryString["pid"] instead of Request["pid"]

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString());

  if(pID ==0)
  {
    //insert query code
  }
  else
  {
   //update query code
  }

}
```

Comment: You might also want to put in some validation and error catching when converting a querystring value to an integer since the querystring can  be easily edited by the user. e.g. check to see if there is value, then check to see if it is numeric.

Comment: Did you take it like this pID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString()); and also give url that contains query string

Comment: There is more to this.  You should be able to use Request["pid"] or Request.QueryString["pid"] and retrieve the value in the button click.  How are you submitting the form?  What page are you posting to?  What does your form tag look like?